# user input validation issues

Tags: python, integer

Whenever I try this it does not work (input = 6). It sends me to the previous menu and says the input is invalid.

[Code in Python that does not work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHVOi.png)

```
def amount_of_Chests () :
    chestCount = 0
    amount_of_Chests_Display ()
    while chestCount <4 :
        chestCount_string = input("Please Make Sure You Enter Enough Chests\nPlease Enter How Many Chests You Would Like (Min.4)")
        chestCount = int(chestCount_string)
        if chestCount < 4 :
            print ("\nThere Are Not Enough Chests, Please Try Again.")
            amount_of_Chests_Display ()
        if chestCount > 3 :
            return chestCount
            amount_of_Bandits ()
        else :
            print ("Sorry that input is not valid. Please try Again.\n")
```

Comment: Not relevant to  your problem but you have a lot of extra spaces in your code: `def amount_of_Chests () :` should just be `def amount_of_chests():` (also the upper-case `C` is bad style)

Comment: that's called camel casing

Comment: Actually, `thisIsCamelCasing`, `ThisIsStudlyCasing`, and `this_is_snake_casing`. I'm not sure what `amount_of_Chests` would be ;) -- in any case, you'll find that *most* Python code adheres to the [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide. If you choose to deviate from the standard, [it should be for a good reason](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M).

Comment: ok fine but can yoou help with my problem

Answer (score 4):

No code after a `return` statement will be executed, so `amount_of_Bandits()` will never be called

Comment: what shall I put instead

Comment: @Adam_0701: I have no idea. It all depends on what your code is supposed to do, and your question leaves out a lot of information. I don't know if you intend to return or not, or if you intend to call `amount_of_Bandits()` instead of returning, or before returning, or not at all.

Comment: I want to return the chests and then go to amount of bandits

Comment: Then you'll have to do that *outside* of your function.